# Sony vaio E Series Display issue

Tags: windows-7, laptop, graphics-card, sony-vaio

I am using sony vaio E series laptop.
i3 processor
4gb RAM
1gb ATI Radeon
I left my laptop running all night , but this is not the first time. Its been 4 years and this system is showing this kind of problem for the first time. The display is scrambled, even the Bios is showing the same problem .
 I am not able to start the laptop in normal mode ,its directly jumps to the BLUE screen saying "dumping physical memory....." but when i start it in safe mode , its working but the display is still messed up. 
NOTE : This problem was fixed automatically for few hours but as soon as i disturbed the laptops position , its display went back to scrap. I am not able to get the problem is it my motherboad is gone or my graphics or its just the wires . Thanx for the help.

Comment: Try this: shut it down, remove AC, removed the battery, let stand for about 30 minutes, then reconnected and restart. Still the same problem?

Comment: @CharlieRB - Thank you for the reply but yes i have tried this.

Comment: @Chenmunka Yes i also wanted to try this but my system starts only in **safe mode** and in safe mode i don't get this option to connect it to projector or any other monitor

Comment: Honestly, our guesses are just wasting your time. You are probably better off having a technician open it up to see what is wrong. Could be a bad motherboard, video adapter or just a loose connector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was problem with the display, my screen was damaged and i had to replace the screen with a new one . It costed my 5000 rupees for a Sony 15 inch screen. The good new is that neither my motherboard nor my graphics card was corrupted which would have been coasted me
 around 12000 rupees.